# Run in to an issue, left joining a table where row 1 can be 2 values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to left joins friend requests, but the way I am handing it, is like so, if the user sends someone a friend request the person sending the request's id goes in to the row 'friend_request_from' and the person receiving the friend request goes in to friend_request_to, now with my select, I am trying to left join requests on another person's id (not the session id) here's what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM timeline_likes
        LEFT JOIN users
             ON timeline_likes.timeline_likes_user = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN timeline_status
             ON timeline_likes.timeline_likes_main_status = timeline_status.timeline_status_id
        LEFT JOIN friends
             ON timeline_likes.timeline_likes_user = friends.friends_friend
        LEFT JOIN friend_request 
             ON timeline_likes.timeline_likes_user = friend_request.friend_request_to   
        LEFT JOIN friend_request 
             ON timeline_likes.timeline_likes_user = friend_request.friend_request_from                             
        WHERE timeline_likes_main_status = ?
             AND timeline_status.timeline_status_enabled = 'enabled'
        GROUP BY users.user_id
        ORDER BY timeline_likes_date ASC
```

Now my problem is, this will only select the sent friend requests `friend_request.friend_request_from` and not the received ones, how can I do something like this (I know what I will write below does not exist I just want to give you an example of what I need

```
 LEFT JOIN friend_request 
        ON timeline_likes.timeline_likes_user = friend_request.friend_request_from 
        OR timeline_likes.timeline_likes_user = friend_request.friend_request_to
```

Because depending on if they sent or received depends on which row their id will go in to.

Comment: could you illustrate with some datasource and ecpecially the resultset you are expecting to get finally?

Comment: The OR should work fine

Comment: thats a lot of left joins. you sure some of those can't be inner joins?

Comment: but the ids are mismatching, if there's more than one for the on statement it chooses the wrong row/